# How to allow to use not-yet-known-type in its type-definition in c?

Tags: c, struct, types, definition

I would like to use type, which is yet not know, becuase I am using it in its own definition:

```
typedef struct{
 int value;
 node_t *next;
} node_t
```

I do not to create new variable (which I would do, If I use tag of that struct (`typedef struct foo{...} foo_t`, where `foo` is a concrete variable) I just want to create new type and use it even in its definition. Is it possible in c?

Comment: Note: there is a semicolon missing from your typedef.

Comment: `typedef struct foo{...} foo_t` does not "create new variable" of any kind. It defines a structure type tagged with `foo`, and aliases it to another name `foo_t`. There is nothing wrong with that (ridiculous impositions of POSIX naming restrictions notwithstanding). If you *really* wanted to you could just use `void *next;` and have the implementation code go cast/conversion crazy, but that's a dreadful idea and no one with a shred of sanity would want to maintain that code base.

Comment: *ridiculous impositions of POSIX naming restrictions notwithstanding* That's a bit over-the-top.  The reservation of `*_t` identifiers for POSIX is no different than the reservation of `__*` and `_[A-Z]*` identifiers by the C standard.  Implementations have to reserve some portion of the singular C identifier namespace in some way.

Comment: So I have decided to use `(*void)` as it is known for compiler in the time of using it (in the struct definition) despite the `node_t` which is not know for compiler in the time of that type definition.

Answer (score 1):

Create the struct first and define a new type based on :

```c
struct node {
   int value;
   struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the structure with the the tag `node_t` beside the `typedef` alias of `node_t`.

This provides a forward declaration of the structure `node_t`, which can be used for pointers to this structure type.

Note that you need to use the `struct` keyword at the declaration of `next`.

```
typedef struct node_t {
     int value;
     struct node_t *next;
} node_t;
```